# Multi CCK field, some not visible

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

I have content type CustomInvoice, which has CCK fields (customer, price, ..etc). Then there is another content type, where all customers are stored. 
In CustomInvoice I have Reference CCK field to CustomerContentType .. so when creating CustomInvoice user would choose customer from drop down cck reference field and that is it.

But if there comes situation when a customer is not yet entered .. user would have to go first create CustomerContent. I would like that this is all done in one form  .. in CustomInvoice.

There would be button Add Customer and jQuery slide would display fields of CustomerContentType and user would fill them .. and then choose this customer from reference CCK field.

Please post some suggestions on this .. how should i do this. Thank you !

Comment: Which Drupal version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The [Popups: Add and Reference](http://drupal.org/project/popups_reference) module provides functionality very close to what you're describing.

Comment: Thanks ! this might be it .. will try